# How do you give a cell format to an ExcelWriterXML results set from a mysqlQueryToTable?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, excel

The problem I'm having trouble with is the following: I am using ExcelWriterXML to extract data from a mySql table and write it into an Excel file. Everything works fine, but I have no control on the cell format that the function mysqlQueryToTable writes. The code is the following:

```
$xml = new ExcelWriterXML($name . ".xml");
$qSheet = $xml->addSheet('Export');
$qSheet->mysqlQueryToTable(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD, $query, $table);
$xml->sendHeaders();
$xml->writeData();
```

At this point everything works, but I can't change the cells in any way, and some results are odd because they are represented in non-specific data formats.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anyone will be able to provide actual code without knowing how you want to change the cells or having a sample of data that is "odd", but here is the documentation on using the [addStyle method](http://excelwriterxml.sourceforge.net/docs/ExcelWriterXML/ExcelWriterXML_Style.html). If that won't let you apply a style after creating a sheet with `mysqlQueryToTable` (which is likely since it seems to be an en masse dump of data), you may have to read the MySQL data (possibly into an array) one row at a time and then write each row (or element) one line at a time so the styles can be applied with the [writeString method](http://excelwriterxml.sourceforge.net/docs/ExcelWriterXML/ExcelWriterXML.html#class_details).